# Pivot values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Have the below table in SQL Server DB:

[image: Original Table]

My aim is to Pivot 'Left', 'Right', 'Centre' based on the **Type** column and derive the below output:

[image: Desired Output]

I'm able to do the above for only one column (say **Left**) using Pivot Query as below:

O/P that I'm getting is:

[image: My Effort]

Need help to drive the table as given in the second figure screenshot.

DDL Scripts to Create the table:

```
Create Table ssis.PivotTable
(
[System] VARCHAR(20)
, Corridor VARCHAR(20)
, RouteId VARCHAR(20)
, [Left] VARCHAR(20)
, [Right] VARCHAR(20)
, [Centre] VARCHAR(20)
, [Type] VARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO ssis.PivotTable VALUES
('Disrupted', NULL, 'WFG-231', '2', '3', '4', 'ABW')
GO
INSERT INTO ssis.PivotTable VALUES
('Disrupted', NULL, 'WFG-231', '3', '4', '4', 'AwW')
GO
INSERT INTO ssis.PivotTable VALUES
('Disrupted', NULL, 'WFG-231', '3', '2', '3', 'AEG')
```

Pivot Query Written by me

```
SELECT [System], Corridor, [RouteId], PivotTable.ABW AS ABW_Left, PivotTable.AwW AS AWW_Left, PivotTable.AEG AS AEG_Left
FROm (SELECT [System], Corridor, [RouteId],[Left], [Type] FROM ssis.PivotTable) AS SourceQuery
PIVOT
(MAX([Left]) FOR [Type] in (ABW, AwW, AEG)) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: On this site we prefer formatted text over images for just about everything, sample data, results, and definitely code. If people can copy your query out along with some DDL/DML statements to create some test data, you'll get a whole lot more people rushing to assist you.

Comment: @Dale Definitely, I'll give the DDL Scripts. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below way -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=174f51d361bfc351ed0c7a9ac7c07a69)**

```
 select [System], Corridor, [RouteId], 
    [ABW_Left], [ABW_Right], [ABW_Center], [AwW_Left],
                [AwW_Right], [AwW_Center], [AEG_Left], [AEG_Right],[AEG_Center]
from
(
    select [System], Corridor, [RouteId], 
        col = type+'_'+col, 
        value
    from PivotTable t
    cross apply
    (
        select 'Reft', [Left] union all
        select 'Right', [Right] union all
        select 'Center', [Centre]

    ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([ABW_Left], [ABW_Right], [ABW_Center], [AwW_Left],
                [AwW_Right], [AwW_Center], [AEG_Left], [AEG_Right],[AEG_Center])
) piv;
```